# how to see if a value is present in a list in django template. tried using IN operator but does'nt work

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to enable a button dynamically but the IN operator on my html does not work. I tried converting everything to string as well but it still did not work.

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='productimages')
    description=models.TextField()
    category=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price=models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart2user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart2product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    productobj=Product.objects.all()
    cartobj=Cart.objects.filter(cart2user=request.user)
    cartobjlist=[x.cart2product for x in cartobj]
    print(cartobjlist)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'productobj':productobj,'cartobjlist':'cartobjlist'})
```

**home.html**

```
 {% for pobj in productobj%}
       <div class="col-xl-3 eachproduct">
        <form action="{%url 'home'%}" method="GET">
          {% csrf_token%}
            <img src="{{pobj.image.url}}" height="300px" width="100%"> 
            <h3 class="name" name="{{pobj}}" value={{pobj}}>{{pobj.id}}</h3> 
            <h3 class="price" name="price" value={{pobj.price}}>${{pobj.price}}</h3> 
            {% if pobj in cartobjlist %}      
              <a href="{% url 'cart'%}" class="btn buttoncart">Go to cart</a>
            {% else %}
              <a href="addtocart/{{pobj.id}}" class="btn buttoncart">Add to cart</a>
            {%endif%}
        </form>
       </div>
       {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did *not* pass the list to the template, you passed a *string* named `'cartobjlist'` to the template. Indeed:

```
{'productobj':productobj,'cartobjlist':'cartobjlist'})
```

That being said, I strongly advice you to fetch the products more efficiently, and furthermore use a set to perform faster lookups, like:

```
def home(request):
    productobj = Product.objects.all()
    cartobjlist = set(Product.objects.filter(cart__cart2user=request.user))
    return render(
        request,
        'home.html',
        {'productobj':productobj,'cartobjlist':cartobjlist}
    )
```

Comment: My bad did not notice the string. And yes, I'll start using sets, just new to things. Thanks for your help Willem. Works perfect :)